# Converting a tensor to a numpy 2D array

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, bert-language-model, transformer-model

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
```

The code included below throws an error on the line:

```
features = bert_encoder([input_word_ids, input_mask, input_type_ids])[0][:,0,:].numpy()
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

I am running this on a tensor flow version > 2.0 and `tf.executing_eagerly()` returns `True`

The dictionary items that I am retrieving information from before the numpy() operation are:

```
{
bert_encoder_output: <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, 
embedding: <tf.Tensor 'tf_bert_model/Identity:0' shape=(None, 50, 768) dtype=float32>
}
```

TPU Session set up:

```
try:
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
    tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
    strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
except ValueError:
    strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy() # for CPU and single GPU
    print('Number of replicas:', strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
```

Code:

```
   from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf

if (tf.executing_eagerly()):
    print ("Yes")
    
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() 

max_len = 50

def get_bert_encoder_output(printInputs = False):
    model_inputs = {}
    bert_encoder = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
    # Get Inputs
    input_word_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_word_ids")
    input_mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_mask")
    input_type_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_type_ids")
    # last hidden-state - the model output - is the first element of the output tuple
    embedding = bert_encoder([input_word_ids, input_mask, input_type_ids])[0]
    bert_encoder_output = (embedding[:,0,:])
    model_inputs['input_word_ids'] = input_word_ids    
    model_inputs['input_mask'] = input_mask
    model_inputs['input_type_ids'] = input_type_ids
    model_inputs['bert_encoder_output'] = bert_encoder_output
    model_inputs['embedding'] = embedding
    if (tf.executing_eagerly()):
     print ("Inside get_bert_encoder_output - Yes executing eagerly")
    features = bert_encoder([input_word_ids, input_mask, input_type_ids])[0][:,0,:].numpy()
    
    if (printInputs):
        print (model_inputs)
        print (features)
        
    return (model_inputs)
```

[image]

Comment: can u add complete traceback?

Comment: Where do you call `get_bert_encoder_output`? What happens if you check `tf.executing_eagerly()` from within that function (it can change depending on where it is called)?

Comment: `get_bert_encoder_output` is called from inside of the `With strategy.scope()` - code included with stacktrace from the error

Comment: In both the calling and called code - `tf.executing_eagerly()` is `true`. These are separate blocks of script executed in the same session one after another - for example first do the `import` and hit Enter key, then set up the tpu and hit Enter key, then execute the function definition `get_bert_encoder_output` and hit Enter key, and finally call `get_bert_encoder_output()` from the `With strategy.scope()`

Comment: Maybe this (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27519#issuecomment-566528842) can help you to understand your error. Your tensor has a shape of (None, 768)

Comment: Hi Hasan, Yes, that makes sense. The `None` is the number of input sentences that will be supplied with the training data. I lost sight of this. It seems that both the steps: Bert Encoder and anything built on top of BERT don't run until we run `model.fit`. I was treating the Bert Encoder step as a separate step and expected it to contain information regarding the encoded form of the raw sentences and thus was thinking that the numpy() should work